# How to find a fit for a function?

Tags: graphics, data

I have the following function:

```
F[t_] := V1 (Cos[w1 t - ph1] Exp[-alpha1 t] - 
     Cos[ph1] Exp[-beta t]) + 
  V2 (Sin[w2 t + ph2] Exp[-alpha2 t] - Sin[ph2] Exp[-beta t])
```

where all the variables are constants.

I want to express it in terms of Spherical Bessel Functions of any type or any linear superposition of them.

My first idea was to extract the data from the function making a list and then use

```
FindFit[data, p SphericalBesselJ[q, t], {p, q} t];
```

But I am struggling to export the data so that it matches the form of a function. I tried:

```
data = Table[F[t], {t, 0, 0.1, 0.0001}]
```

But the label of the x axis is 1,2,3.... where I need 0.0001, 0.0002 and so on.

Any ideas of how to get around it or maybe another way of finding the correct expression of `F[t]` in terms of Bessel Functions?

Comment: Welcome! What is `data` and `expression`? What axis (plot?) are you talking about? You should supply working code to help reproduce your results.

Comment: You do realise that not all variables are constants, right ? Second: You are trying to plot something that has non-numerical values; You should provide numerical values for the different parameters - `V1`, `w1`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
This work for me.

```
V1=ph1=beta=V2=w2=ph2=alpha2=alpha1=w1=1;
F[t_]:=V1 (Cos[w1 t-ph1] Exp[-alpha1 t]-Cos[ph1] Exp[-beta t])+V2 (Sin[w2 t+ph2] Exp[-alpha2 t]-Sin[ph2] Exp[-beta t]);
data=Table[{t,F[t]},{t,0,0.1,0.0001}];
FindFit[data,p SphericalBesselJ[q,t],{p,q} ,t]
(*{p->2.646290764,q->0.9164426788}*)
```

Comment: That gives me the x range, but not the why range no? what I want is to extract a list with x,y pairs where x are 0.0001.... and y f[0.0001]